# Equinox vs Solstice?

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry, spheres

I have just learnt that a solstice and equinox are different by definition.

From what I understand, a solstice is when the rays of the sun are parallel to the equator, but I can't quite understand how an equinox is defined?

Some more mathematical explanations would be super helpful, and maybe even a diagram if possible?

I imagine this might have links to polar coordinates?

Comment: You might find [this youtube lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSfc7gx3RLk) helpful.

Comment: The word “equinox” literally means “equal night.”

Answer (score 0):

**Solstice** (or solstitium) is latin for "sun (level) ending", i.e. the day of maximal or minimal height of the sun path, so it comes in summer or winter.

**Equinox** is latin for equal night, i.e. where day and night have same lengths, so it comes in spring or autumn.

--- rk